# Netty ByteBuf processing, decoders structure in the pipeline

Tags: java, netty

My server sends response to the client or forward the message to another client depends on message content.
I need to use 8 bytes messages: 6 encrypted bytes between braces, for example:

```
0x3C 0xE1 0xE2 0xE3 0xE04 0xE5 0xE6 0x3E
```

Where 0x3C means < sign as an opening frame marker, and 0x3E means > sign as closing frame marker.

If internal 6 encrypted bytes (0xE1 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06) are decrypted successfully, data contains same markers again:

```
0x3C 0x3C 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x3E 0x3E
```

So I get 4 bytes payload (0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05).

I have already written a FrameDecoder, but now I can't decide to strip the braces bytes or not:

- I want to write clean code, braces are only frame markers so they belong to FrameDecoder responsibility. This means for me FrameDecoder needs to strip them. But on forwarding, FrameEncoder needs to add them again (on reponse encoding too). I can simply write the closing marker into the buffer but I don't know how can I write single byte to the beginning of Bytebuf efficiently.
- If I do not strip markers, it looks not so clean solution, but I can forward the entire received Bytebuf (after encryption) or last handler can allocate 8 bytes for the entire Bytebuf on reponse sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you split the decryption and transformation into two handlers.
The first one's responsibility is just to decrypt raw data. The second is to transform the raw data into pure message. The benefit of this kind of solution is that if some one wants to change decryption method later, he can just need change the first handler without affect the second one.  Likewise, the transformation method can also be changed without affect decryption.